# WPF and softwarename.exe.config

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF project that saves some values ​​in softwarename.exe.config file.
When I update the app.config file and recreate the installation package softwarename.exe.config the file is not updated.
How can I update it?

Answer (score 0):

To test using the normal exe's config file un-check the box for "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process" in the "Debug" tab in the project properties menu. That will make visual studio no-longer use the vshost.exe file to launch and the correct config file will be used.[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
I think, however, do not in my case.
The problem I have when releasing the software to end-users, not being debugged.